# Object Variable Error in VBA Printing Script

Tags: excel, vba, object, printing, datamatrix

I recently moved a Excel vba project from my personal computer to my work computer. This project is meant to connect and print using a Brother Printer. I keep getting a Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set. This impeads me being able to print anything using my work computer. But when I connect and use the vba on my personal computer it seems to run fine and the error does not occur. Though when stepping through the code I don't see anything in the Locals window that would indicate the issue.

```
    Dim CreateLabel As VbMsgBoxResult
    Dim labelInfo As String
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim ObjDoc As Object

    ' Step 1: Ask the user if they wish to create a label
    CreateLabel = MsgBox("Do you wish to create a label?", vbYesNo)

    If CreateLabel = vbYes Then
    
        ' Step 2: Prompt for each parameter
        Dim licensePlate As String
        Dim partNumber As String
        Dim Description As String
        Dim expirationDate As String
        
        Dim validInput As Boolean
        Dim userInput As String
        
        ' Step 2a: Enter SupplierPlateID with exit option
        'Do
            'userInput = InputBox("Enter SupplierPlateID" & vbNewLine & _
                                 "Press 'Cancel' to terminate the process.")
            'If userInput = "" Then Exit Sub
            'licensePlate = userInput
            licensePlate = InputBox("Enter License Plate:")
            'validInput = ValidateSupplierPlateID(licensePlate)
            'If Not validInput Then
             '   MsgBox "Invalid SupplierPlateID."
            'End If
        'Loop While Not validInput

        ' Step 2b: Enter Part Number with exit option
        Do
            userInput = InputBox("Enter Part Number (must have two '-' and end with '-875')" & vbNewLine & _
                                 "Press 'Cancel' to terminate the process.")
            If userInput = "" Then Exit Sub
            partNumber = userInput
            validInput = ValidatePartNumber(partNumber)
            If Not validInput Then
                MsgBox "Invalid Part Number. It must have two '-' and end with '-875'."
            End If
        Loop While Not validInput

        Description = InputBox("Enter Description:")

        ' Step 2c: Enter Expiration Date with exit option
       expirationDate = InputBox("Enter Experation Date (YYYY-MM-DD)" & vbNewLine & _
                                "Press 'Cancel' to terminate the process.")

        ' Step 3: Validate and display entered information
        labelInfo = licensePlate & " | " & partNumber & " | " & Description & " | " & expirationDate
        confirmMsg = "Is the following information correct?" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & labelInfo
        confirmed = MsgBox(confirmMsg, vbYesNo) = vbYes
        
        
        'Update the label's caption with the user-created string in the Userform
        UserForm1.Label3.Caption = labelInfo
        

        ' Step 4: Allow correction or confirmation
        If Not confirmed Then
            ' Provide an option to go through the steps again if the information was incorrect
            Call CreateAndPrintLabel
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        ' Store labelInfo in cell B12 on Sheet1
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B12").Value = labelInfo
        
        
        
         ' Step 5: Confirm if user wants to print
            printLabel = MsgBox("Do you wish to print the label?", vbYesNo)
    
                
                If printLabel = vbNo Then
                    Exit Sub ' Exit the macro if user selects "No" for printing
                End If
            
            ' Step 5.5: Print the label using Brother printer
            Set ObjDoc = CreateObject("bpac.Document")
            sPath = "C:\Users\55455.buff\Documents\My Labels\Matrix.lbx"
            
            
            
            ' Open lbx file
            If ObjDoc.Open(sPath) Then
                ' Set text for the entire label
                ObjDoc.SetText 0, dataMatrixContent
                
                ObjDoc.GetObject("dataMatrix").text = labelInfo
                
                ' Print the label
                ObjDoc.StartPrint "", bpoDefault
                ObjDoc.PrintOut 1, bpoDefault
                ObjDoc.EndPrint
                
                ' Close lbx file
                ObjDoc.Close
            Else
                MsgBox "Failed to open label file."
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "ActiveX Data Matrix control not found on the sheet."
        End If
    'End If
End Sub
Function ValidatePartNumber(partNumber As String) As Boolean
    If CountCharacter(partNumber, "-") = 2 And Right(partNumber, 4) = "-875" Then
        ValidatePartNumber = True
    Else
        ValidatePartNumber = False
    End If
End Function

Function CountCharacter(ByVal text As String, ByVal character As String) As Long
    CountCharacter = (Len(text) - Len(Replace(text, character, ""))) / Len(character)
End Function

Function IsValidExpirationDate(expirationDate As String) As Boolean
    Dim regex As Object
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    regex.Pattern = "^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$"
    
    If regex.Test(expirationDate) Then
        Dim currentDate As Date
        currentDate = Date
        Dim futureDate As Date
        futureDate = DateAdd("yyyy", 6, currentDate)
        
        If DateValue(expirationDate) <= futureDate Then
            IsValidExpirationDate = True
        End If
    End If
End Function

Function ValidateSupplierPlateID(supplierPlateID As String) As Boolean
    If Len(supplierPlateID) = 8 And Left(supplierPlateID, 2) = "PC" Then
        ValidateSupplierPlateID = True
    Else
        ValidateSupplierPlateID = False
    End If
End Function

Sub Print_Label()
    Dim bRet As Boolean
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim ObjDoc As bpac.Document
    Set ObjDoc = CreateObject("bpac.Document")
    sPath = "C:\Users\giovanni.fontanetta\Documents\My Labels\Matrix.lbx"
    
    'Open lbx file
    bRet = ObjDoc.Open(sPath)
    If (bRet <> False) Then

        ' Start Print-Setting
        ObjDoc.StartPrint "", bpoDefault

        ' Ask the user how many copies to print
        Dim numCopies As Integer
        numCopies = InputBox("Enter the number of copies to print:", "Number of Copies", 1)

        For i = 1 To numCopies
            ObjDoc.PrintOut 1, bpoDefault
        Next i

        ' Finish Print-Setting and start the printing
        ObjDoc.EndPrint

        ' Close lbx file
        ObjDoc.Close
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You have an `On Error Resume Next` that you have cropped out, and your `Set ObjDoc = CreateObject("bpac.Document")` fails because you don't have that software installed on your computer?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that below line is causing the issue possibly due to incorrect installation of brother printer driver or related software on your work computer.

```
Set ObjDoc = CreateObject("bpac.Document")
```

You can possibly put some Debug.print or Msgbox statements at several places in the code to narrow down and understand which portion of the code gives the error.

Comment: Within my current reference library I have a Brother b-PAC 3.1 Type Library. If I go back and look at the working vba on my personal computer, I see that its b-PAC 3.2 Type Library.  I did not notice this before. Could this contribute to why it won't work?

Comment: You can try adding the reference to that correct Type Library in Tools=>Reference menu.

Comment: I was able to redownload the reference library. Also adding in proper debug.prints. It appears that I can't set the DataMatrix text when `ObjDoc.GetObject("Data_Matrix").text = labelInfo`

Comment: Did you enter Debug.print before each and every line to narrow down to exact line or are you suspecting that line as error came somewhere around that. At times without putting enough debug.print statements we pinpoint incorrect line.

Comment: I came to this conclusion because, after adding in Debug.print's after each interval of changes within my current code, I'm seeing that before the above code, I see in the Immediate window that I've set the text for the entire label. However, once I get to the above line of code, I can't get that debug.print, and the code gets an error. Giving me the understanding that I can't set the users `labelInfo` as the text for the datamatrix

Comment: I've been able to resolve the issues of getting any errors. However now it seems that even with no errors running through my code, I get no response to the printer.

Comment: Do you still have on error resume next in the code?

Comment: No. I don't nor did I ever see that when I was looking at the code.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently after contacting Brother support, and then rerunning the code with the printer, the answer was found. The reason why the macro was able to work on my personal laptop but not work laptop was because it was in 32-bit. Apparently, Brother doesn't support this feature of using Excel to print to printers on 64-bit systems. Which was what the work computer was running at.

In each of my testing I was able to prove this by repeating printing steps on 64 vs 32 bit systems. Each 32-bit was capable of receiving the message from Excel, and printing. While on 64-bit the printer could run through a test print through Windows, as well as manually printing. But no connection was possible when receiving messages from Excel.  Furthermore, this was evident as the Brother Printer Add-ins Utility, which allows the Microsoft Suite of programs to communicate to the printer, is grayed out and unavailable on the 64-bit computer compared to the 32-bit.